# Move data using Button But only True Entries in Google Form Response

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I Have data in "Form responses 1". I want to move data from "Form responses 1" sheet to "Verified Form Response" Sheet. The condition is that entries which are marked as True in Column W should move, not all the entries.

The link of the sheet is:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LUUEZ7sSjBy-WWL3TZt8l6sqtrEBn3dZ03iRDTY1bF0/edit?usp=sharing

The code I am using is:

```
function copyInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet5SS");
  
  var pasteSheet_size=pasteSheet.getRange('A2:A').getValues().filter(String).length;
  var source_size=copySheet.getRange('A2:A').getValues().filter(String).length;
  var source_range = copySheet.getRange(1,1,source_size,copySheet.getLastColumn());

  var move_data = source_range.getValues().filter(row=>row[23]==true);
  var source_data = source_range.getValues().filter(row=>row[23]==false);
  pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet_size+1,1,move_data.length,move_data[0].length).setValues(move_data);
  
  source_range.clearContent();
  copySheet.getRange(1,1,source_data.length,source_data[0].length).setValues(source_data);
        
}
```

Comment: Hi, would you let me know if my answer solved your issue so I can modify it if it didn't ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

You are very close.

- You need to start the range from the second row:

  `copySheet.getRange(2,1,source_size,copySheet.getLastColumn());`
- and the checkboxes are in **column W**, therefore in column number **22**:

  `filter(row=>row[22]==true);`

---

**Solution:**

```
function copyInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Verified Form Responses");
  
  var pasteSheet_size=pasteSheet.getRange('A2:A').getValues().filter(String).length;
  var source_size=copySheet.getRange('A2:A').getValues().filter(String).length;
  var source_range = copySheet.getRange(2,1,source_size,copySheet.getLastColumn());

  var move_data = source_range.getValues().filter(row=>row[22]==true);
  var source_data = source_range.getValues().filter(row=>row[22]==false);
  pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet_size+1,1,move_data.length,move_data[0].length).setValues(move_data);
  
  source_range.clearContent();
  copySheet.getRange(2,1,source_data.length,source_data[0].length).setValues(source_data);
        
}
```

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LUUEZ7sSjBy-WWL3TZt8l6sqtrEBn3dZ03iRDTY1bF0/edit?usp=sharing                                                                                This script is doesn't delete row from Form Response Sheet. When user submit data using Google Form it appears after entries which have been moved and Also this script isn't working fine. There are two entries left which doesn't move and this script shows error.

Comment: Also this sheet is shared with User. When he click on Submit Button this script doesn't run.

Comment: And also while copying the data sometimes it copies data in verified form where data already exist

Comment: @Admin-RKPareekCo Hi. When I built this code I didn't know that the source sheet you are using is a form response sheet. The latter does not work as a regular sheet. When the user submits a form, the data is not necessarily appended in the last row, but in the row after the last submission was made. That means that we need to delete the row everytime we move data. But that wasn't in the scope of this question. Could you please post a new question regarding this issue? Namely, how to move form response entries to a different sheet or something like that. Thanks :)

Comment: I posted new Question